# Как передать значение переменной JS методом POST AJAX JS?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

есть ссылка с атрибутом data-id, запускающая модальное окно, и следом идет AJAX JS скрипт

```
<a id="updatedetail" href="" data-id="1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#upDetail">Изменить</a>

<script>
 $('#updatedetail').click(function() {
  var showid = this.dataset.id; 
  $.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "modal.php",
  data: { showid: showid },
  success: function() {
   alert(showid);   
  }
 })
})
</script>
```

В модальном окне следующая конструкция

```
<?php $id = $_POST['showid']; ?>
<p>ID = <?php echo $id; ?></p>
```

В результате команда alert(showid) выводит значение переменной, а в модальное окно в $id не попадает. Где может быть ошибка в коде?

Comment: У вас разметка же статичная? Или html код прилетает в ответ на аякс?

Comment: почему вы решили, что запрос не работает? напишите так: `success: function(data) { alert(data); }` так вы получите ответ сервера по запросу. и с этим ответом уже можно работать.

Comment: @Андрюха, так у меня alert(data) вообще не выводится, а сразу открывается модальное окно

Comment: @capchuck , разметка статичная

Comment: не вижу отмены перехода по ссылке

Comment: @АлександрЗинченко ну теперь смотрите. Пыха у вас выполняется на сервере, HTML/JS в браузере. 1. Браузер запрашивает страничку (GET /page) ->  Отрабатывает пыха, отправляет статичную разметку -> Браузер делает POST -> ??? Что должно произойти дальше на серваке и что должно произойти в браузере? Если вы ожидаете, что после аякса должна открыться модалка а-ля ваш шаблон модалки, то пыха должна вернуть HTML код, браузер его получить и нарисовать.

Comment: @capchuck , в конечном итоге мне нужно каким-то образом передать значение JS переменной в переменную PHP